# How to get the first value of a column that satisfies a condition with groupby in R?

Tags: r

I have the following `data table`

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id_resp = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), week=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4), val=c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,2))
```

I would like to get the first `week` that has `val > 0` for every `id_resp`

Is there a neat way to do this in R ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `aggregate` without assuming that `df` is sorted:

```
aggregate(week ~ id_resp, data=dt[dt$val>0,], FUN=min)
#  id_resp week
#1       1    3
#2       2    4
```

*Getting the first value of a column that satisfies a condition* can be done like:

```
aggregate(week ~ id_resp, data=dt[dt$val>0,], FUN=function(x) {x[1]})
#  id_resp week
#1       1    3
#2       2    4
```

Comment: I like this solution better because it returns only the interesting columns

Answer (score 2):

We can use `.I` in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt[dt[, .I[first(which(val > 0))], by = id_resp]$V1, ]

#   id_resp week val
#1:       1    3   1
#2:       2    4   2
```

Using `dplyr`, we could use `slice` using similar logic

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
  group_by(id_resp) %>%
  slice(first(which(val > 0)))

#   id_resp  week   val
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1       1     3     1
#2       2     4     2
```

If we are sure that every `id_resp` would have at least one `val` greater than 0, we can replace `first` and `which` with `which.max`.

```
dt[dt[, .I[which.max(val > 0)], by = id_resp]$V1, ]
```

and

```
dt %>%  group_by(id_resp) %>%  slice(which.max(val > 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dt[val > 0][!duplicated(id_resp)]
#    id_resp week val
# 1:       1    3   1
# 2:       2    4   2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `.SD` to subset

```
dt[, .SD[which(val > 0)[1]], by = id_resp]
#  id_resp week val
#1:       1    3   1
#2:       2    4   2
```

---

Or with `.I`

```
dt[dt[, .I[val > 0][1], id_resp]$V1]
#   id_resp week val
#1:       1    3   1
#2:       2    4   2
```

If we need only specific column

```
dt[, .(week = week[which(val >0)[1]]), by = id_resp]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
  group_by(id_resp) %>%
  filter(val > 0, !duplicated(val))
```